# Construct if statement on TCHAR array

Tags: c++

I have this code which prints the computer name.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain(void)
{
    TCHAR buffer[256] = TEXT("");
    TCHAR szDescription[8][32] = { TEXT("NetBIOS"),
        TEXT("DNS hostname"),
        TEXT("DNS domain"),
        TEXT("DNS fully-qualified"),
        TEXT("Physical NetBIOS"),
        TEXT("Physical DNS hostname"),
        TEXT("Physical DNS domain"),
        TEXT("Physical DNS fully-qualified") };
    int cnf = 0;
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(buffer);

    
        if (!GetComputerNameEx((COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT)0, buffer, &dwSize))
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("GetComputerNameEx failed (%d)\n"), GetLastError());
            return;
        }
        else _tprintf(TEXT("%s: %s\n"), szDescription[0], buffer);
        if (buffer == TEXT("DESKTOP-SURPO18")) _tprintf(TEXT("CORRECT"));
        dwSize = _countof(buffer);
        ZeroMemory(buffer, dwSize);
    
}
```

I just want to  create or construct a simple if statement like if(buffer  == text("MyComputerName")) tprint(TEXT("CORRECT")); but it's not working. Or can you suggest other simplest way of code like I posted above that work with if statement easily using a computer name? Thank you.

Comment: `using tstring = std::basic_string<TCHAR>; if (tstring(buffer) == TEXT("MyComputerName") ...`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `std::string_view` would be another solution without memory allocations or string copies.

Comment: `if(buffer == text("MyComputerName"))` -- The reason this does not work is that you are comparing two pointer values.  Arrays are not comparable using `==`.

Comment: `GetComputerNameEx((COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT)0, buffer, &dwSize)` -- This will not work if the build is Unicode.  The `dwSize` is supposed to be the number of `TCHAR's`, not the number of bytes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik and namespace "std" has no member "basic_string".

Comment: @itTech `#include <string>` -- Did you add that include?

Comment: Thank you sir @PaulMcKenzie it worked. God bless you all :)